# Apply t.test on a tidy format data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, p-value

I have a data frame in tidy format as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D") ,
             group = c(rep("case", 3), rep("cntrl", 4)), 
              mean = rnorm(7, 0,1))
```

I would like to group the data by two variables name and group and apply a t.test on mean value of each category. For example doing t.test between A_case.vs.A_cntrl and add pvalue as the result to the table.

Do you have any idea how can I do this using tidyverse package?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

here, a group wise, `t.test` on 'name' cannot be performed as there is only a single observation for each pair.  Instead, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(ttest = list(t.test(mean[group == 'case'],
                                  mean[group == 'cntrl']))) %>% 
   pull(ttest)
```

#### Update

If we need to create a column, use `mutate`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(pval = t.test(mean[group == 'case'],
                               mean[group == 'cntrl'])$p.value)
```

---

Or reshape to 'wide' format and then do the `t.test` on the columns

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = mean) %>% 
   summarise(ttest = list(t.test(case, cntrl))) %>% 
   pull(ttest)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I would like to add a column pvalue to the wider version of table where I use t.test between case and control in each row. I also have edited my data because in my real data set the number of case and controls are not equal. this is what I am trying...  test <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = mean) %>%
  mutate(ttest = t.test(case, cntrl)$p.value))

Comment: These values can be considered as mean values that I would like to compare to see how significant is their difference. maybe t.test is not a good option to use since it is getting 2 vectors of values.

Comment: @say.ff that would be a different question though